# Is there a way to detect logical structure amongst text segments of technical documents?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language, text-mining

Suppose there is an API document with few function descriptions.
As a human i am able to grasp the dependency amongst functions on each other even if it is not specifically mentioned. 
For instance if there are functions displayList() and CreateList(), I know that in order to display a list i need to first have it created.

Is there any work in NLP that can detect such logical relations amongst subtopics in technical documents and give a list of related functions given a natural language description of task to be accomplished.

I have found these two works that are somewhat similar but only do a text-to-code translation, but they don't address the issue highlighted in my question.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00468

https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04815